# Как получить размер View элемента из атрибутов в android?

Tags: android, java, view

Использую кастомный View элемент основанный на RelativeLayout, в конструкторе получаю атрибуты, если размер указан в - "dp", то работает прекрасно, но если ставлю `MATCH_PARENT` программа падает при инициализации, как получить размер если указанно `MATCH_PARENT` а не к примеру 150dp?

```
private void init(AttributeSet attrs, Context context)
{
    int[] attrsArray = new int[] 
    {
        android.R.attr.id,               // 0
        android.R.attr.layout_width,     // 1
        android.R.attr.layout_height     // 2
    };

    final TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);

    try 
    {
        // Получаем Id
        Id = typedArray.getResourceId(0, View.NO_ID);
        // Ширина
        m_nWidth  = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(1, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            // Высота
        m_nHeight = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(2, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        m_nWidth = 200;
        m_nHeight = 200;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Освобождаем ресурсы
        typedArray.recycle();
    }
}
```

Конструктор:

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs, context);
}
```

Лог:

> 04-22 13:38:18.695:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1992): FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
> Can't convert to dimension: type=0x10
> 04-22 13:38:18.695:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1992):   at
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
> 04-22 13:38:18.695:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1992):   at
> com.test.view.CustomView.init(CustomView.java:63)
> 04-22 13:38:18.695:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1992):   at
> com.test.view.CustomView.<init>(CustomView.java:26)

Comment: На какой строке падает то?

Comment: Падает на typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(1, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

Comment: причина понятна - 0x10 это код из R.class, который есть MATCH_PARENT, потому при конвертинге падаем. Может лучше не переопределять эти значения? 

Comment: Мне нужно получить размер View чтобы в нем по середине нарисовать объект

Comment: наверное надо использовать другие методы для получения высоты и ширины контейнера, они всеравно будут только после отрисовки на экране

Comment: Разве конструктор не получает размер перед отрисовкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим вам надо нарисовать что-либо на View после получения его размеров.

Можно применить такой вариант: Сделать CallBack отрисовки типа void DrawCallback(View view) и там, где вам надо проверять размеры View делаете так.

```
  int measuredWidth = target.getMeasuredWidth();
  int measuredHeight = target.getMeasuredHeight();
  if (measuredWidth == 0 || measuredHeight == 0) {
    new Deferer(target, mDrawCallBack);
    return;
  } else {
    mDrawCallBack(target);
  }
```

Deferer:

```
class Deferer implements ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
DrawCallback callback;
ImageView targer;
Deferer (ImageView target, DrawCallback callback) {
    this.target = new WeakReference<ImageView>(target);
    this.callback = callback;
    target.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(this);
  }

@Override public boolean onPreDraw() {
ImageView target = this.target.get();
if (target == null) {
  return true;
}
ViewTreeObserver vto = target.getViewTreeObserver();
if (!vto.isAlive()) {
  return true;
}

int width = target.getMeasuredWidth(); 
int height = target.getMeasuredHeight();

if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
  return true;
}

vto.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

callback(target);
return true;
}
```

Работу не проверял, но должно выстрелить с минимальными поправками :)

Answer (score 1):

> Разве конструктор не получает размер
> перед отрисовкой?

Нет не получает. Размер становится известен только поcле отработки:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout()
```

отсюда и исходите, вкурите Google что ли...